# Implementing method into the progress Bar

Tags: java

Here I got an action listener of a Button and a method to make iterate the progress Bar, how can I implement the method into the progress Bar?

I had tried pb.setString(iterator); but obviously, it didn't work because SetString only accepts Strings.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
                {
                    pb = new JProgressBar(0,100);
                    pb.setBounds(80, 80, 160, 30);
                    pb.setValue(0);
                    pb.add(iterator());
                    pb.setStringPainted(true);
                    pb.setVisible(true);
                    frame.add(pb);

                }
            });

    void iterator() throws InterruptedException
        {
            int i = 0;
            while(i < 100)
            {

                pb.setValue(i);
                i = i+5;
                Thread.sleep(300);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html).

```
SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
    protected Void doInBackground() {
          //do stuff
          setProgress(progressValue); //when you want to update the progress, do this
    }

}
worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() { //this runs whenever the progress is changed, to actually set the progress of the JProgressBar
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                if ("progress" == evt.getPropertyName()) {
                    int progress = (Integer) evt.getNewValue();


                    pb.setValue(progress);

                }
            }

        });
worker.execute();
```